# Advise: Two way Communication between Applications using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two Applications Application A and Application B which needs to send two way messages. Any advise how to achieve using spring boot? I should not use any Messaging services. Please advise what can be used to solve the problem.

Below is a diagram on the scenario.

[image]

Comment: You want to send messages - but don't want to use the mechanism (messaging services) to accomplish this? Is there a reason you cannot use Messaging?

Comment: @Randy Casburn. Messaging services are part of rejected software to be used. Hence thinking if any framework to be used with spring-boot can help for two way communication. Please advise.

Comment: Two options: 1) Classic Microservices architecture using RESTful services (can only be pull) 2) Socket communication (Websockets perhaps) that would allow persistent two way push/pull comms

Comment: @Randy Casburn I'm thinking to take the Websockets way. However, could you please help to any learning material/ or Github link to explore more? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider WebSockets. Quite simple to implement.

Here is a link to the Spring WebSockets documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket

And here is a Spring.io tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

This will get you started using a Server with Browser as client. Simply duplicate the server (rather than use a browser) and you'll have one solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say duplicate the server what class do i need to duplicate? As client uses Stomp to subscribe and send to topic. How do i replace with server code? Please advise. Thanks again

Comment: I just meant "instead of using a browser client for Application B, you can use Spring Boot using the same technique."

Comment: I understand as Application A (Spring-Boot without Client) and Application B (Spring-Boot without Client) can communicate with each other? if so then how to add Stomp to subscribe and send/receive to/from topic. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Invoke a controller method (properly annotated) on App A to SEND message (magical via STOMP) that App B controller will receive (STOMP will magically route request) at properly annotated controller method. Here is a sample controller  with annotated methods: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/#_create_a_message_handling_controller and here is the config for STOMP: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/#_configure_spring_for_stomp_messaging